# in React.js, my state isn't updating on the first click but the second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have to click items on my dropdown menu twice in order for the state to update the content shown on the page. I included a video and some code snippets. How can I go about changing that?

[image]

Parent Class Component (APP):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: 'Africa', // region is owned by Parent component
      countries: [],
    }
  }

  updateRegion = (type) => {
    this.setState({
      region: type
    })
  }
```

API FETCH

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const apiURL = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`;
      const response = fetch(apiURL)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            countries: data
          });
        })
  }
```

Rendering App

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <section>
        <div id="search">
          <div id="search_dropdown">
            <Menu regionUpdate = {this.updateRegion}/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <CountryList countries = {this.state.countries} region = {this.state.region}  />
      </section>
    </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child Classless Component (Menu):

```
export default function SimpleMenu(props) {
  const [type, updateType] = React.useState('Africa');

  const onRegionClick = (e) => {
    updateType(e.target.innerText);
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    props.regionUpdate(type);
  }
```

Returning Menu

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>
        Filter by Region
      </Button>
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem onClick = {onRegionClick}> Africa </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick = {onRegionClick}> Americas </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick = {onRegionClick}> Asia </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick = {onRegionClick}> Europe </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick = {onRegionClick}> Oceania </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `state` updates asynchronously, you can't be sure that the state update will happen before `props.regionUpdate` is called. Just pass the target value directly.

```
const onRegionClick = (e) => {
   updateType(e.target.innerText);
   // console.log(type);  ---> it would log the old, previous value
   props.regionUpdate(e.target.innerText);
}
```